# How do I convert this zsh function to fish shell?

Tags: zsh, fish

I have this function which works great in zsh, but I want to convert it to fish shell and I can't get it working.

```
function ogf () {
  echo "Cloning, your editor will open when clone has completed..."
  source <(TARGET_DIRECTORY=~/students EDITOR=$EDITOR clone_git_file -ts "$1")
}
```

Comment: You should show us what solutions you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, since fish's syntax differs from zsh, you also have to change the output of `clone_git_file` to `source` it.

For example, if `clone_git_file` is something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "FOO=$TARGET_DIRECTORY"
echo "BAR=$2"
```

you have to change it to fish syntax.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "set -gx FOO $TARGET_DIRECTORY"
echo "set -gx BAR $2"
```

Now here's the `ogf()` function, and sample code for fish:

```
function ogf
  echo "Cloning, your editor will open when clone has completed..."
  source (env TARGET_DIRECTORY=~/students EDITOR=$EDITOR clone_git_file -ts $argv[1] | psub)
end

ogf MY_ARGUMENT
echo "FOO is $FOO"
echo "BAR is $BAR"
```

Running this code with fish, the output is:

```
FOO is /home/MY_USER/students
BAR is MY_ARGUMENT
```

Comment: Nice answer. To emphasize, note the use of `env` and `psub`

Comment: Thank you for this, I will give it a try today and accept the answer as long as it works!

Comment: There is also the `bass` plugin which makes it easy to use scripts which output sh/bash/zsh variable assignment statements into valid fish syntax: https://github.com/edc/bass

Comment: I've never seen `psub` before.  Why not just eval the output?