# Calling another function in fish shell

Tags: fish

I received [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691787/how-do-i-convert-this-zsh-function-to-fish-shell) excellent answer on how to convert a zsh function to a fish function. Now I have another question. How do I call that function from another function, passing on the argument?

I have tried this:

```
function ogf
  echo "Cloning, your editor will open when clone has completed..."
  source (env TARGET_DIRECTORY=~/students EDITOR=$EDITOR clone_git_file -ts $argv[1] | psub)
end

function wogf
  env EDITOR=webstorm ogf "$argv[1]"
end
```

but I get "env: ogf: No such file or directory".

The goal is only to change the `EDITOR` environment variable for this one execution, and then call `ogf`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `env` command can only run other external commands. It cannot call shell builtins or functions; regardless whether the shell is fish, bash, or something else. The solution is to define the function being called with the `--no-scope-shadowing` flag and use `set -l` in the calling function:

```
function ogf --no-scope-shadowing
  echo "Cloning, your editor will open when clone has completed..."
  source (env TARGET_DIRECTORY=~/students EDITOR=$EDITOR clone_git_file -ts $argv[1] | psub)
end

function wogf
  set -l EDITOR webstorm
  ogf $argv
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to write your function to use its own arguments, as follows:

```
function ogf
  echo "Cloning, your editor will open when clone has completed..."
  source (env TARGET_DIRECTORY=~/students EDITOR=$argv[2] clone_git_file -ts $argv[1] | psub)
end

function wogf
  ogf $argv[1] 'webstorm'
end
```

Maybe this is a simpler example on how to call another function while passing arguments:

```
function foo
  bar "hello" "world"
end

function bar
  echo $argv[1]
  echo $argv[2]
end
```

Then calling `foo` will print:

```
$ foo
hello
world
```